# Are Cookie IDs recycled?

Tags: browser, cookies

Once a cookie ID is deactivated/deleted by a browser, can the cookie ID be recycled? For example, if User A is tagged with CookieID A which expires in say 30 days, can a User B be assigned the same CookieID at a later time?

I guess a better question could be 'How is a CookieID generated?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "CookieID" in general. Cookies do not have a predefined meaning, they just act as key=value storage – the website tells the browser to store some data and the browser starts attaching it to future requests.

This means that each website defines its own meaning and format of the cookies it sets – it might use a cookie to store a "session ID" of some kind, or it might not. If it stores a session ID, it might generate the ID based on a PRNG or a HMAC or a signature or just current timestamp.

That said, session IDs are *usually* generated completely randomly, to make accidental ID duplication very unlikely. (For example, some websites just use an 128-bit UUID for this purpose.) There is no practical advantage to recycling session IDs, it only adds to possible security risks.